# Access an internally used list

Tags: java, list, methods

I'm coding the Dijkstra algorithm in Java. My first method

```
public void populateDijkstraFrom(Node startNode)
```

creates a Linked List of nodes with its respective distances and predecessors. My second method

```
public List<Node> getShortestPath(Node startNode, Node targetNode)
```

is supposed to create a list of nodes with the shortest path from the startNode to the targetNode using the list of nodes from my populateDijkstraFrom method.

However, I don't know how to access the list of nodes from my Dijkstra method in the getShortestPath method. I could change the return type from void to LinkedList but I was told that it works using void.

How do I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are basically two ways of solving this.

Easiest one would be return the list of nodes on your method

```
public List<Node> populateDijkstraFrom(Node startNode) {
       // ^ Configure to return list instead of void

    // ......
    return nodeList;
}

public List<Node> getShortestPath(Node startNode, Node targetNode) {
    List<Node> pdList = populateDijkstraFrom(startNode);
    // ^ --- Get the list by simply passing the same parameter to the method
}
```

Another is stated by Gian

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you get the `populateDijkstraFrom` method to store its result in some member of the enclosing class, at which point it is accessible from `getShortestPath`, e.g.:

```
public class Foobar {
    private List<Node> distances;

    public void populateDijkstraFrom(Node startNode) {
       // ...
       distances = ...
    }

    public List<Node> getShortestPath(Node startNode, Node targetNode) {
       // use distances here!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the structure of your Node class.

You don't need to change the signatures. Depends on your structure. I would expect something like (with appropriate getters and setters)

```
public class Node {
    List<NodeConnection> nodeConnections;
}


public class NodeConnection {
    Node targetNode;
    long distance;
}
```

So you're iterating over the nodeConnections on the startNode to find a path to the target node.

Comment: That would be a little odd.  That would entail encoding edges back into the input graph and having to traverse a linked list of nodes?